# How can I make this struct work in C?

Tags: c, struct

I've been trying to learn structs in C and can't figure out how to make this code to work. I keep getting this error:

```
incomplete type 'struct card' struct card aCard = {"Three", "Hearts"};

^
test.c:2:8: 

note: forward declaration of
      'struct card'
struct card aCard = {"Three", "Hearts"};
```

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct card aCard = {"Three", "Hearts"};

int main(void){
printf("%s", aCard.suit);

}
```

Comment: You need to define what `struct card` is before declaring any variables of that struct type. Something like `struct acard { const char *number; const char *suit; };`

Comment: C does not have type inference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define the structure:

```
struct card {
   char  type[4];
   int  value;
};
```

And then you can declare it :

```
struct card card1; /*Declaration card1 of type card*/
```